# Pass data via jQuery ajax from several drop down

Tags: jquery, loops

Everybody: I need to send data from 20 drop downs to a PHP file. How can I make some loop over them to see values to all of them? Thanks you.

P.S.: In PHP I know how to walk through them to get the data...

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I've got table with 2 cols and about 10 rows but user can add or remove rows.In every <td> I've got drop down.in every col drop downs are the same.I need to see what values are selected in all elements in first col then in second and send them vie ajax to php file to be saved in DB.

Comment: @stackoverflow - a very **official** edit made by a very *official* user ;)

Comment: @Lix - What is your point honey? Or did you just need some activity to do, so you can finally get Mortarboard badge? You made it. Congratulation :)

Comment: @stackoverflow, No point :) There was a discussion recently mentioning your username - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125665/is-the-profile-username-stackoverflow-legal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take this HTML as a sample -

```
<div id="vanyov">
  <select>
    <option value="Beer"></option>
    <option value="Wine"></option>
    <option value="Water"></option>
    ...
  </select>
  <select>
    <option value="Steak"></option>
    <option value="Pizza"></option>
    ...
  </select>
  ...
</div>
<!-- I hope I put the right choices in here.
everyone cool with Beer and Pizza right? ;) -->
```

You could use jQuery to return all the select elements you need and then parse though all of them adding them to a JSON object.

```
var valuesJSON = {};
$.each($("#vanyov select"),function(index,elem){
  valuesJSON[index] = $(elem).val();
});
```

This would add the values of all the `<select>` elements with in the `#vanyov` element.

But what's going on here?  Lets take a look -

- `var valuesJSON = {}` - This is some shorthand code to create a new empty object named valuesJSON.
- `$.each` - This is a jQuery function that will loop though all the elements you give it.  Arrays and Objects and especially groups of elements that [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) return.  There is also a callback function that is passed each of the items that `$.each` found.
- `$("#vanyov select")` - Here we are telling jQuery to give us all of the `<select>` elements that are descendants of the `#vanyov` element.
- `valuesJSON[index]` - This is where we are adding a new item to the JSON.  We use the `index` parameter because they are right there! Easy! The `$.each` function provides them.
- `$(elem).val()` - We wrap the `elem` parameter with `$()` to convert it into a jQuery object and then we use the `val()` function to extract the value of the `<option>` element within the dropdown that was selected.

Then send out your order with an Ajax call perhaps -

```
$.post('/ajax/lyubomir',valuesJSON,function(response){
  // Return values here
},"json");
```

<sub>I hope they come soon - After that, I'm starving...</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create an array of values you should definitely check the [serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method.  You will find an excellent [usage example](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/#entry-examples) on the same page is you scroll down a little bit.